# auth: couldn't find user mongodb@admin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

Try to connect and use a database in `Node.js` + `MongoDB` + `OpenShift` combo from script, but get this error in log file:

```
Wed May 20 06:12:37.337 [conn23] auth: couldn't find user mongodb@admin, admin.system.users
Wed May 20 06:12:37.338 [conn22]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "mongodb", nonce: "4ecbda68de309435", key: "ca66aa2d830a43e4741d1aa44158b454" }
```

any idea?

here is the code:

```
var connection_string = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nodejs';
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    connection_string = 'mongodb://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}
connection.connect(connection_string, function (err, _db) {
var db = MongoClient.db(req.params.db);
```

Comment: Do you have something like `app.use(express.bodyParser());`?

Comment: solution here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/ **Indirectly Against Another Database** need `?authSource=admin` at the end of the connection string

Comment: For what it's worth you can also use RockMongo to admin your OpenShift MongoDB instance: https://hub.openshift.com/addons/29-rockmongo